# How to create deep type object in typescript

Tags: typescript

How to create deep type or interface object in typescript? Example:

```
const messagesEn = {
  "main": {
    "content": "Main content"
  },
  "title": "Title",
  "header": {
    "breadcrumbs": {
       "link": "Link"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: I need to describe the type of object that is listed above

Comment: I tired Record<string, string>

Comment: TypeScript will infer the type of that object with high precision. Hover over the `messagesEn` declaration in your IDE and you'll see either what you want or a very strong starting point for an a `type` or `interface` definition.

Answer (score 4):

You might be looking for the `typeof` operator:

```
const messagesEn = {
  "main": {
    "content": "Main content"
  },
  "title": "Title",
  "header": {
    "breadcrumbs": {
       "link": "Link"
    }
  }
};

type MessagesEn = typeof messagesEn;
```

```
// Result:
type MessagesEn = {
    main: {
        content: string;
    };
    title: string;
    header: {
        breadcrumbs: {
            link: string;
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple types to achieve what you want, making the types reusable in   other types too.

```
export type TypeContent = {
    content: string
}
export type TypeBreadcrumb = {
    link: string
}
export type TypeHeader = {
    breadcrumbs: TypeBreadcrumb[]
}

export type TypeMessage = {
    main: TypeContent
    title: string
    header: TypeHeader
}

const messagesEn : TypeMessage = {
    "main": {
      "content": "Main content"
    },
    "title": "Title",
    "header": {
      "breadcrumbs": [{
         "link": "Link"
      }]
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry, but it's answer doesn't not fit, because it not for dynamic object